# How to get table row details when redirecting

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I'm working with Flask and MySQL to create a table that gets populated based on the database. Now, when a user clicks on a particular row, I need to redirect to another page that will tell me more about that particular row.

I have the redirection part down but how do I get information about that row on the backend?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in resultPois %}
    <tr onclick="window.document.location='/pageDetail';">
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

On the flask side:

```
@app.route('/pageDetail')
def page_detail():
    # get info here to render page!
    return render_template('page_detail.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `flask.url_for(endpoint, **values)` when you want pass the variable from template to the backend.

In Flask template:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in resultPois %}
    <tr onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('page_detail', rowData=row) }}';">
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

In Flask view:

```
@app.route('/pageDetail/<rowData>')
def page_detail(rowData):
    # you can use the the rowData from template
    return render_template('page_detail.html'
```

BTW, What I suggest to design the front end part, better make button as one column in the table row, when click the button, then trigger the onclick function to call url_for, that will be more user friendly.